# JQuery find a div with a certain classname and specific text

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is is find an elements from all the child elements within my parent element (el) that have a certain class and a certain text. I just want the div

This works `$(el).children().find("div")` and finds all the children

So I want the div with inner text **"hello"** with a class of **"selected"**

```
$(el).children().find("div").text("hello").hasClass("selected");
```

The line above doesn't do anything or has some were side effect of changing all this child elements text to something random.

I am def NOT a jquery expert and can't seem to find the right combination of selectors to get the job done

Comment: hasClass returns true/false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using class selector and contains together, this should do

```
  var childs =   $(el).find("div.selected:contains('hello')");
```

Comment: Oh man, I was soooo close. I tried `.find()` but could not get it to work. Thanks loads for your help. Just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little off. Firstly you can use `find()` alone without calling `children()` first, `hasClass` returns a boolean not a jQuery object, and `text()` is used to set a value, not find an element.

To do what you require you should put the class on the selector in the `find()` call, then use `:contains` to search for the element with the relevant text content. Try this:

```
$(el).find("div.selected:contains('hello')")
```